# Inverting a text not working in css

Tags: html, css

I need to rotate a text 90 degree. I have followed several things including stackoverflow but couldnt invert the text.

My css is:

```
.semiInverted {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

JsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AE2z2/

Can anybody help me?

Comment: how about this: `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);`

Comment: @Govan its used to make sure every well known browser (eg. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera) will use your CSS3 transform attribute correctly

Comment: @user2002495 not working. Try it in fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element should be a block element, otherwise it can't be rotated. Furthermore `<text>` is no valid HTML tag; use `<span>` or `<div>` instead. Finally you shouldn't only use the Mozilla specific CSS property (`-moz-…`). The correct CSS would be:

```
.semiInverted {
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AE2z2/1/)**

Comment: Why you are using display: inline-block. else its not working?

Comment: @Govan Yes. The element should be a block-level element; otherwise it can't be rotated.

Comment: You told that using <text> we cannot rotate but @rajeshkakawat has done it using text.

Comment: @Govan It might work, but `<text>` is no valid HTML element. It'd be the same as using `<randomblah>` for your tag. Check out this list of [valid HTML tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

`text` is not a valid HTML tag.  Switch the `text` tag to a `span` and it should work.

**CSS**

```
.semiInverted {
    display: inline-block;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform:  rotate(90deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
Inverted Text:<span class="semiInverted">&nbsp;&#8250;</span><br>
Normal Text:<span>&nbsp;&#8250;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using the experimental, Firefox only version of the property. Get rid of `-moz-`
2. You are trying to style a `<text>` element, which does not exist in HTML. Use a `div` or another [transformable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology) instead.

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an
>     element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either
>     a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>     property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>     table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in
>     the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the
>     attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine if you use normal HTML and css (I tried it using paragraphs)
    http://jsbin.com/AJosAfan/1/watch?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AE2z2/3/)

```
.semiInverted {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     display:block;
     float:left;
}
```

Comment: It works fine.. May I know the reason why my code didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is just make the element an inline block

http://jsfiddle.net/AE2z2/29/

```
.semiInverted {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div >
        Inverted Text: <span class="semiInverted" >  &nbsp;&#8250;  </span>
     <br>
    Normal Text:<text>&nbsp;&#8250;</text>
         </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .semiInverted {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
-o-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
transform:rotate(-180deg);
ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)";
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/AE2z2/74/